# Browser prompts for credentials for a web app with windows authentication enabled on iOS

Tags: ios, iis, browser, single-sign-on, windows-authentication

I have an intranet website with windows authentication enabled. It works fine on windows machine i.e. when i am connected to the network it logs me using my windows credentials.
When I open the same application on a browser(Safari or Chrome) on any iPhone, which is also on the network, it prompts for credentials. Though, it logs me in successfully on entering credentials but asks for credentials again on form submit or reload.
Please provide your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your Application Pools user if have permission over the folder or any file your app using.

Comment: Can you please let me know where specifically should I check the permissions. The configured user is ASP.NET Identity User. Also, if that is the case, should be behavior be not same for both windows and iOS?

Comment: your app is running on what?

Comment: My  app is deployed on a windows machine, on IIS server, with windows authentication enabled. When I open the app on windows machine, it automatically logs in user but when i open the app on iOS, it prompts for credentials on each page load.

Comment: first add the IP of the server to the intranet zone in your browser configuration..  

And you cant do this two things.
Change your web.config adding this values.
E.G.
`<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <allow users="yourdomain\someotheruser" />
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>`

or given permission of read to the IUSR user, in the folders where your app is running. _c:\inetpub\wwwroot\YourWebSite_